# There are unrecoverable which must be corrected first

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, import

I can't import an eclipse project to android studio.
[image: Here's the screenshot.]

Hope someone can help me with this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide mode details?

Comment: @user3300758 : Can i have whole sentence 'Library reference..\\' here so that i can identify which property to remove from eclipse project..?

Comment: * Project PacsafeConcessionaire:C:\Users\User\Downloads\eugenealvizo-ulitc-54b7bd5d88fb\eugenealvizo-ulitc-54b7bd5d88fb\PacsafeConcessionaire\project.properties:
Library reference ..\..\..\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-071a61c\actionbarsherlock could not be found
Path is C:\Users\User\Downloads\eugenealvizo-ulitc-54b7bd5d88fb\eugenealvizo-ulitc-54b7bd5d88fb\PacsafeConcessionaire\..\..\..\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-071a61c\actionbarsherlock which resolves to C:\Users\User\Downloads\JakeWharton-ActionBarSherlock-071a61c\actionbarsherlock

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please follow below steps :

1. Go to your eclipse project root directory
2. Open project.properties
3. remove dependancy that contains 'ActionBarSherlock'

   **android.library.reference.1=../library that contains ActionbarSherlock**
4. Import project to Android Studio
5. Add manually removed library or jar or module
6. Rebuild it

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it. :)

Comment: How do you add the library back in Android Studio 1.5.1?

Comment: Greate Dude Really Appriciated